# How to set input with image for tensorflow-lite in c++?

Tags: c++, embedded-linux, tensor, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to move our Tensoflow model from Python+Keras version to Tensorflow Lite with C++ on an embedded platform.

It looks like I don't know how set properly input for interpreter.

Input shape should be (1, 224, 224, 3).

As an input I am taking image with openCV, converting this to CV_BGR2RGB.

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<tflite::FlatBufferModel> model_stage1 = 
tflite::FlatBufferModel::BuildFromFile("model1.tflite");
  TFLITE_MINIMAL_CHECK(model_stage1 != nullptr);

  // Build the interpreter
  tflite::ops::builtin::BuiltinOpResolver resolver_stage1;
  std::unique_ptr<Interpreter> interpreter_stage1;
  tflite::InterpreterBuilder(*model_stage1, resolver_stage1)(&interpreter_stage1);

TFLITE_MINIMAL_CHECK(interpreter_stage1 != nullptr);

  cv::Mat cvimg = cv::imread(imagefile);
  if(cvimg.data == NULL) {
    printf("=== IMAGE READ ERROR ===\n");
    return 0;
  }

  cv::cvtColor(cvimg, cvimg, CV_BGR2RGB);

  uchar* input_1 = interpreter_stage1->typed_input_tensor<uchar>(0);

 memcpy( ... );
```

I have issue with proper setup of memcpy for this uchar type.

When I am doing like this, I have seg fault during working:

```
memcpy(input_1, cvimg.data, cvimg.total() * cvimg.elemSize());
```

How should I properly fill input in this case?

Comment: Instead of memcpy why not loop over all values in `cvimg` and set them like `interpreter_stage1->typed_input_tensor<uchar>(0)[i] = x;`, where i is the index and x the value?

Comment: OK, but how RGB pixels should be placed in memory? { 0,0R 0,0G 0,0B 0,1R 0,1G 0,1B ... n,mR n,mG n,mB } ?

Comment: The answer is in your question: Since you use `cv::cvtColor(cvimg, cvimg, CV_BGR2RGB);` your cvimg contains them in RGB order just as in your previous comment.

Comment: Thank you. This way is putting data properly to input_1 array, but I am not sure is it correct. No matter what data I will load there I am getting the same answers.

Comment: I think it might actually be common to put images in a 1-dimensional array like this. OpenCV does it, FLTK is another library i know, that does it.

Answer (score 2):

To convert my comments into an answer: 
Memcpy might not be the right approach here. OpenCV saves images as 1-dimensional arrays of RGB-ordered (or BGR or yet another color combination) color values per pixel. It is possible to iterate over these RGB-chunks via:

```cpp
for (const auto& rgb : cvimg) {
    // now rgb[0] is the red value, rgb[1] green and rgb[2] blue.
}
```

And writing values to a Tensorflow-Lite typed_input_tensor should be done like this; where i is the index (iterator) and x the assigned value:

```cpp
interpreter->typed_input_tensor<uchar>(0)[i] = x;
```

So the loop could look like this:

```cpp
for (size_t i = 0; size_t < cvimg.size(); ++i) {
    const auto& rgb = cvimg[i];
    interpreter->typed_input_tensor<uchar>(0)[3*i + 0] = rgb[0];
    interpreter->typed_input_tensor<uchar>(0)[3*i + 1] = rgb[1];
    interpreter->typed_input_tensor<uchar>(0)[3*i + 2] = rgb[2];
}
```

Comment: OK, currently I cannot assign nothing to interpreter->typed_input_tensor<uchar>(0)[i]. Every try of assigment is giving me seg fault

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it at least for the single channel case. This assumes that the opencv bufffer is contiguous. So, in this case, tensor dims are (1, x, y, 1).

```
float* out = interpreter->typed_tensor<float>(input);
input_type = interpreter->tensor(input)->type;
img.convertTo(img, CV_32F, 255.f/input_std);
cv::subtract(img, cv::Scalar(input_mean/input_std), img);
float* in = img.ptr<float>(0);
memcpy(out, in, img.rows * img.cols * sizeof(float));
```

OpenCV version - 4.3.0
TF Lite version - 2.0.0

nada's approach is also correct. Pick whichever suits your programming style, however memcpy version is going to be comparatively faster.

Comment: that's very helpful. I am new to cpp and was hoping if you can help me out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71392038/tflite-inference-using-cpp